# Connect Android Devices using bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have two android devices, and I want to connect them using bluetooth programming, sorry for say but I don't want to see the links on Android Developer Documentations.

I want to connect them without any permission like password or anything else, so just simply connect two devices and start sending files and receive files without any permission, 
how can I implement such concept?

Help me please, I am stuck on this.

Comment: Hey veer.. did you get the issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Short, you can't. You'll need at least the Bluetooth permissions as illustrated in the tutorial on the Android Docs-Page.

Comment: but these we can remove from menifest, by adding some code, it is in chat example by android developer

Comment: Why do you say : "I don't want to see the links on Android Developer Documentations". Did you try the bluetooth chat made by the Android team ?

Answer (score 1):

You have everything here :

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

Get the code, run it and see how it works.